# Issue with ACME's Distributional Reinforcement Learning Implementation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, acme-deepmind

I've been using DeepMind's ACME library for some of my Reinforcement Learning projects and I've come across an issue that I'm hoping someone can shed light on.

**Libraries and Environment**

- Python 3.9
- TensorFlow 2.8
- Acme by DeepMind

**The Code**

I am working with `learning.py` where I've noticed that the variables `q_tm1` and `q_t` are tensors:

```
q_tm1 = self._critic_network(o_tm1, transitions.action)
q_t = self._target_critic_network(o_t, self._target_policy_network(o_t))
```

These are later passed to a function losses.categorical in the `distributional.py` file, which is implemented as follows:

```
def categorical(q_tm1: networks.DiscreteValuedDistribution,
                r_t: tf.Tensor,
                d_t: tf.Tensor,
                q_t: networks.DiscreteValuedDistribution) -> tf.Tensor:
  z_t = tf.reshape(r_t, (-1, 1)) + tf.reshape(d_t, (-1, 1)) * q_t.values
  p_t = tf.nn.softmax(q_t.logits)
  ...
```

**The Problem**

The function expects both `q_tm1` and `q_t` to be instances of `DiscreteValuedDistribution`. However, they are tensors as generated in `learning.py`. Consequently, the program crashes when trying to access the values and logits attributes of `q_t` and `q_tm1`:

```
z_t = tf.reshape(r_t, (-1, 1)) + tf.reshape(d_t, (-1, 1)) * q_t.values
p_t = tf.nn.softmax(q_t.logits)
```

**Questions**

Is this behavior intentional, or perhaps an oversight?
If it's intentional, what would be the workaround to ensure proper functioning?
If it's not intentional, how could one go about fixing it?

**What I've Tried**

**Tensor to `DiscreteValuedDistribution` Conversion:** One of the initial thoughts was to convert the `q_tm1` and `q_t` tensors into instances of `DiscreteValuedDistribution`. However, this approach was impractical as I didn't have access to the corresponding logits or probs, which are essential for initializing a DiscreteValuedDistribution.

```
# The following wouldn't work without logits or probs
q_tm1_as_dvd = networks.DiscreteValuedDistribution(values=q_tm1, logits=???)
q_t_as_dvd = networks.DiscreteValuedDistribution(values=q_t, logits=???)
```

**Modifying categorical Implementation:** Another potential fix considered was to alter the implementation of the `losses.categorical` function in `distributional.py`. However, this could create ripple effects affecting other parts of the codebase, including:

Breaking other algorithms that may rely on this function.
Potentially introducing new bugs, especially if the original design was intentional.
Invalidating any existing tests that were designed based on the current behavior of the function.
Given these constraints, I'm hesitant to make large-scale changes without better understanding the implications and design choices behind the existing code. So any help or insights are greatly appreciated!